# how to get the last digit from the IP address?

Tags: php

Does anyone know how can I get the last digit number from the Ip address in php?

example:

```
$ip = '200.0.0.12';
```

How can I get only 12 from the IP address instead of 200.0.0.12?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the ip is well-formed (no ports, ipv4, etc)

```
$last_digit = array_pop(explode('.', $ip))
```

Answer (score 4):

I like Mike B's answer, but here's a possible alternative: use [`strrchr`](http://php.net/strrchr) and [`substr`](http://php.net/substr):

```
$ip = '200.0.0.12';
echo substr(strrchr($ip,'.'),1);
```

One advantage: it's supposed to be (a little) faster then Mike B's answer.

In my (very unscientific) timings i got an average runtime of 1.3562 seconds (500.000 iterations) versus 1.6590 seconds for the array_pop / explode version.

Answer (score 0):

My alternative. By this way you get last digit in number type, not in string

```
$ip = '200.0.0.12';
echo ip2long($ip) % 256;
```